# How to prove the following bosonic entanglement expression?

Tags: entanglement, information-theory, entropy, entanglement-witness

Based on the article given by [J. L. Ball, I. Fuentes-Schuller, and F. P. Schuller, Phys. Lett. A 359, 550 (2006)](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0506113)
had used the following expression of von-Neumann entropy

\begin{equation}
S = - \operatorname { Tr } \left( \varrho  \log _ { 2 } \varrho \right) = \log _ { 2 } \left( \frac { \left| \gamma _ { B }  \right| ^ { \left( 2 \left| \gamma _ { B }  \right| ^ { 2 } \right) / \left( \left| \gamma _ { B }  \right| ^ { 2 } - 1 \right) } } { 1 - \left| \gamma _ { B } \right| ^ { 2 } } \right)
\end{equation}
where,
\begin{equation}
| \gamma | ^ { 2 } \equiv \left| \beta _ { k } / \alpha _ { k } \right| ^ { 2 }
\end{equation}
provided with,
\begin{equation}
\varrho = | \overline { 0 } _ { - k } \overline { 0 } _ { k } \rangle \left\langle \overline { 0 } _ { k } \overline { 0 } _ { - k } |\right.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}{\label{eq34}}
| \overline { 0 } \rangle = \sum _ { n = 0 } ^ { \infty } c _ { n } | n _ { k } n _ { - k } \rangle
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
c _ { 0 } = \sqrt { 1 - \left| \frac { \beta _ { k } } { \alpha _ { k } } \right| ^ { 2 } }
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
c _ { n } = \left( \frac { \beta _ { k } ^ { * } } { \alpha _ { k } ^ { * } } \right) ^ { n } c _ { 0 }
\end{equation}

I tried to substitute by these expressions but without success. I appreciate your answers.

Comment: Would you be able to type up your working so that it's possible to figure out what's gone wrong?

Comment: Since the calculation takes long time to retype on Stackexchange, the last step I arrived is, I have to show that, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n \log (x^n) = \log\left(x^{x/(1-x)^2}\right)$

Comment: And that is guaranteed if I didn't miss this, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n  = \frac{1}{1-x}$

Answer (score 1):

We have,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
S &= - \operatorname { Tr } \left( \varrho  \log _ { 2 } \varrho \right) = \log _ { 2 } \left( \frac { \left| \gamma _ { B }  \right| ^ { \left( 2 \left| \gamma _ { B }  \right| ^ { 2 } \right) / \left( \left| \gamma _ { B }  \right| ^ { 2 } - 1 \right) } } { 1 - \left| \gamma _ { B } \right| ^ { 2 } } \right) = \log _ { 2 } \left( \frac { \gamma   ^ { \gamma  / \gamma -1 } } { 1 - \gamma  } \right) \\&= -  \left(\frac{\gamma}{1-\gamma} \log _ { 2 }\gamma + \log_{2}(1-\gamma) \right)
\end{aligned} \label{a} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where we shortened our expressions by, $\gamma = \gamma_B^2$.

On the other hand we believe that,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
S &= - \operatorname { Tr } \left( \varrho  \log _ { 2 } \varrho \right) = - \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} c_n^2 \log(c_n^2) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \gamma^n(1-\gamma) \log_2\left(\gamma^n(1-\gamma)\right) \\&= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \gamma^n(1-\gamma) \left( 
\log_2\ (\gamma^n)+\log_2(1-\gamma )\right) \\&= (1-\gamma ) \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \gamma^n \log_2\ (\gamma^n)+ (1-\gamma ) \log_2 (1-\gamma ) \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \gamma^n 
\end{aligned} \label{b} \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Now, those sequences have the following closed form providing that, $|\gamma|<1$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \gamma^n = \frac1{1-\gamma} \\
\text{and},\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \gamma^n\log \gamma^n &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \gamma^n n \log \gamma=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \gamma \gamma^{n-1} n \log \gamma =\log \gamma\left(\gamma\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\gamma^n\right)'\right) \\&= \log \gamma\cdot \frac \gamma{(1-\gamma)^2}=\log \gamma^{\gamma/(1-\gamma)^2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
It follows that we can subsitute these results in eq.(\ref{b}) to obtain eq.(\ref{a})

[For reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3268064/is-this-sequence-defined-correctly#3268071).